# Is there any method in selenium to get that text is a "Link" or simple text

Tags: python, selenium

Is there any method in selenium to get that text is a Link or simple text

Comment: Can you give us some more information on what you are exactly trying to do and other like DOM structure etc..

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you get innerText of element and now want to validate whether it is under  node.

Consider following HTML snippet for this -

```
"<a title=\"Junior TSG Application Engineer at Two Sigma Investments. Click to learn more.\" target=\"_blank\" " +
            "href=\"http://careers.stackoverflow.com:80/jobs/10467/junior-tsg-application-engineer-two-sigma-investments?campaign=PrettyTopspot\"> " +
            "Junior TSG Application Engineer<br> <span class=\"company\">Two Sigma Investments</span><br> <span class=\"location\">New York, NY</span> </a>";
```

Here innerText is - "Junior TSG Application Engineer"

You can get page html using getHTMLSource api of selenium and then can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) to find out if its in anchor tag, i.e. -

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(selenium.getHTMLSource);
    Element element = document.select("a:contains(Junior TSG Application Engineer)").first();
    System.out.println(element.nodeName()); // You could do assertion here
```

> On a different note, do you know Selenium questions would have their dedicated home at - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/
>   You might like to post your question here.

Comment: I guess you use Selenium - Python binding. You should be able to find similar parser in Pythin

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like `isThisLink(String textToBeValidated)`, then no. Selenium doesn't have such a method. You will have to write custom code to validate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **is_element_present('link=' + text)**. This will return true if text is a link otherwise false. Caution: You need to escape special characters in text. While testing this I was looking for a link that had a question mark in it and it was not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can user getText() method in the below way:

selenium.getText("ID or xpath");

Happy Learning , Happy Sharing...